# Deshabilitar color (resaltado) de sintaxis - Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio

Fuí a:

`Tools` -> `Options` -> `Environment` -> `Fonts and Colors`

Pero parece que sólo puedo deshabilitar cada elemento (display item) uno por uno, cambiando su estilo.

Hay alguna opción global, o al menos alguna opción para deshabilitar el color por lenguaje, por ejemplo, para C++.

Answer (score 0):

No hay un *interruptor* con el cual se pueda *apagar* el resaltado de sintaxis en Visual Studio 2008, como ya has descubierto, tienes que ir poniendo el mismo estilo a todos los elementos en `Tools/Options/Environment/Fonts and Colors`.